# Use diferent class depend on g++ flag

Tags: c++, g++, c-preprocessor

I want my C++ program to work in one of two modes: normal/debug.
For now I've got some `class A`, which I want to replace with `class N` when `normal mode` or with `class D` when `debug mode`.
What's the clean way of doing it?
I was thinking about sth like:

```
// classA.h
#ifdef DEBUG
#include "./classD.h"
#else
#include "./classN.h"
#endif
```

But how can I easily make this class "compatible" with previus `class  A` interface?

Comment: Why would you want separate classes? Doesn't that make doubles the code base for you, making you work twice as much? I would rather see parametrizing class N with a template parameter to optionally enable debugging, but a separate class? What is the use case?

Comment: This means that you debug something different, than what is deployed. What are you trying to solve? Sounds like an [x/y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: In my case I want to separate classes because i need different class configuration (like ip, etc) when building  program for debug locally, and when building program to run on server. I thought It would be best to make it changeable with compile options (Because changes are related to build) But ofc I will be grateful for some advice, how to do it in a proper way.

Comment: EDIT* And those changes are not limited to changing one string to other. -> Simple parametrizing is not enought.

Comment: You need to provide more information. One way to do this could be to provide a factory, which creates an appropriately configured object.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot help myself but to mention that what you want to do is a little fishy. Unless `A` is specifically for debugging I wouldn't want it to be a different class in debug / release builds. As mentioned in a comment, you typically want to debug the code that you later release, not some different code. This sounds like a recipe for confusion.

Having said that, you can make `A` an alias to either of the two:

```
// classA.h
#ifdef DEBUG
#include "./classD.h"
using A = D;
#else
#include "./classN.h"
using A = N;
#endif
```